# What character set do I need to correctly encode Japanese in a CSV to be opened in Excel?

Tags: asp.net, excel, encoding, csv

My asp.net application is supposed to export a dataset as a CSV file to open in Excel. The dataset has Japanese double-width kanji characters in addition to English characters.

I've tried a number of different combinations of headers, character sets and content encoding, but I haven't been able to find the right combination that allows Excel to open the file and show the Japanese characters correctly.

If, however, I open the file in Notepad and then save it using UTF-8 encoding, I can then open the file in Excel and see the Japanese characters as intended. Therefore it must be possible, but I can't find the right combination of headers to make it work without opening and saving the exported file in Notepad.

```
Private Sub TestCSV()

    Dim context As HttpContext = HttpContext.Current

    context.Response.Clear()
    context.Response.ClearHeaders()
    context.Response.ClearContent()
    context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
    context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=test.csv")
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/csv"        
    context.Response.Charset = Encoding.UTF8.WebName

    context.Response.Write("English,Japanese")
    context.Response.Write(Environment.NewLine)
    context.Response.Write("Test,日本語")

    context.Response.End()

End Sub
```

Any help getting this code to work would be greatly appreciated.

I also tried using the following lines of codes in various combinations and orders, but nothing worked.

```
    context.Response.BinaryWrite(Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble())
    context.Response.BinaryWrite(Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-16le").GetPreamble())
    context.Response.Charset = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-16le").WebName
    context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "text/csv; charset=utf-16")
    context.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1250")
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! I added some other languages and symbols just to make doubly sure.

The key was to set the charset in the header, the content encoding *and* the preamble all to UTF-8.

```
Private Sub TestCSV()

    Dim context As HttpContext = HttpContext.Current

    context.Response.Clear()
    context.Response.ClearHeaders()
    context.Response.ClearContent()
    context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/csv"
    context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=test.csv")
    context.Response.Charset = Encoding.UTF8.WebName
    context.Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8
    context.Response.BinaryWrite(Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble)

    context.Response.Write("Language,Sample")
    context.Response.Write(Environment.NewLine)
    context.Response.Write("Symbol,™£©€®")
    context.Response.Write(Environment.NewLine)
    context.Response.Write("Japanese,日本語")
    context.Response.Write(Environment.NewLine)
    context.Response.Write("Chinese Simplified,中文(简体)")
    context.Response.Write(Environment.NewLine)
    context.Response.Write("Spanish,Español")
    context.Response.Write(Environment.NewLine)
    context.Response.Write("Chinese Traditional,中文(繁體)")
    context.Response.Write(Environment.NewLine)
    context.Response.Write("Korean,한국어")

    context.Response.End()

End Sub
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
/// <summary>
/// method to export report into excel
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
protected void linkProcess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename={0}.xls", "YTDReviewsData"));
    Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
    Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
    Response.BinaryWrite(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetPreamble());      
    System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
    gvDealDetails.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
    Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
    Response.End();
}
```